# Is an XSS attack possible under these constraints?

Tags: web-browser, xss, javascript, html

The output is:

`<img src="http://example.com/[input]" oncontextmenu="openUrl('http://example.com/[input]')">`

Where **[input]** is the user input, which is sanitised through this function:

```
a => {
  a = String(a);
  a = this.replaceAll(a, "&", "&amp;");
  a = this.replaceAll(a, '"', "&quot;");
  a = this.replaceAll(a, "'", "&#39;");
  a = this.replaceAll(a, "<", "&lt;");
  return a = this.replaceAll(a, ">", "&gt;")
}
```

in other words, we seemingly can't break out or use quotes of any kind?

Is an XSS attack possible at all under these constraints? Or is it possible to redirect the user to any domain besides example.com? Or indeed, load an image from (or make a request to) evil.com? Thanks!

Comment: Looks solid from here.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, XSS is possible.

The first injection into `src` is secure, as `"` is HTML encoded, which is a proper defense against XSS in a HTML attribute value context.

The second injection however is insecure, as it takes place in a JavaScript attribute context. Here, HTML encoding is not a proper defense and XSS can be achieved by injecting `');alert('1`, which would give you (I replaced the undefined `openUrl` function for a self-contained POC):

```
<img src="http://example.com/[input]" oncontextmenu="console.log('http://example.com/&#39;);alert(&#39;1')">
```

While this may look secure at first sight, it is not. Right-clicking on the image will execute the payload. This is the case because the HTML parser first decodes the HTML-encoded `&#39;` before passing it to the JavaScript interpreter.

The proper solution here is a bit tricky. You do need the HTML encoding for `"`, but you also need to backslash-escape `'` (either in its HTML-encoded or basic form). `\` will also need to be escaped.

Comment: I don't follow why this gives you XSS.  You have not escaped the string context at all.  You've modified the `console.log` statement, but now you're just logging the literal string `alert` - you aren't triggering an alert.

Comment: @ConorMancone No, I'm not logging the literal string `alert`, I am triggering the alert (the explanation is in the second to last paragraph). I've verified this with firefox and chrome. Do let me know if there are browsers where this doesn't work though. The change of `console.log` is just so that users can copy-paste and try the code as-is, without having to define `openUrl`.

Comment: Ah, I was briefly confusing the HTML `#39` escape for javascripts `\x27`.  Too much gibberish.  Still, the OWASP XSS mitigation cheat sheet *strongly* discourages using a backslash for escaping in a JavaScript context: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#rule-3-javascript-encode-before-inserting-untrusted-data-into-javascript-data-values  This is because it is often done improperly and is also escaped by an escape-the-escape.

Comment: Instead, you should basically just replace everything with it's `\xHH` equivalent (in this case, replace the `'` with `\x27`)